# cx_Oracle. How to access remote machine?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I had a look at cx_Oracle but I have a couple of problems with it. First , my oracle server is on remote machine. Second I do not know on what platform my software will be deployed. All the examples I have founded

like this 
http://www.len.ro/2009/08/cx_oracle-on-ubuntu-9-04-jaunty/
 or 
this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592/cx-oracle-how-do-i-access-oracle-from-python

assume to have oracle server on the same machine. Is there possibility to have some static compilation so I can easily move my software from one pc to the other?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course cx_Oracle can work with server working on other machine. But on client machines you will have to install Oracle client and configure it. I don't know if Oracle client installation can be added to installer of your application. Normally it is huge (600 MiB or so) so it is not a good idea. Then on all client machines you will have to configure Oracle client: set `ORACLE_HOME`, run Oracle tools to configure connection with database etc.

The only "light" solution I know is to use JDBC from Jython or Java. In this scenario you can use "thin" version of connect string that requires only some `.jar` libraries. Such connect string looks like:

```
db = DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:oracle:thin:169.0.1.225:1521:test_db', 'user', 'passwd')
```

On client machines it needs `ojdbc6.jar` and `orai18n.jar` on `CLASSPATH`. No installation, no configuration, simple and easy.

Comment: oracle client __~140MB__; oracle-xe __~400MB__

Comment: Some clients are very big, on: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/111060-win32soft-099267.html there is "Oracle Database 11g Release 1 Client (11.1.0.6.0) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)" that is 510,809,607 bytes